# Create table based on JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I have some JSON which I would like to put into a table, but one of the items in the dict should be in a separate table at the top.

```
{
"test": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  },
"test2": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  }
}
```

I would like to loop through the test dict's and parse table from them underneath each other like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/JcARE]

I have it working for the 1/2/3/4/5 table but am unable to put the upper row in the code as well... with:

```js
$(function() {
  var tbody = $("<tbody />"),
    tr;
  $.each(trades, function(_, obj) {
    tr = $("<tr />");
    $.each(obj, function(_, text) {
      tr.append("<td>" + text + "</td>")
    });
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
  });
  tbody.appendTo("#trades_table");

})
```

```html
<table class="table" id="trades_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is append a `row` with `colspan` of `5` with text as key value before iterating over the array like this:

```js
var trades={
"test": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  },
"test2": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  }
};
$(function() {
  var tbody = $("<tbody />"),
    tr;
  $.each(trades, function(_, obj) {
    tr = $("<tr />");
    tr.append("<td colspan='5' align='center'>" + _ + "</td>")
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
    tr = $("<tr />");
    $.each(obj, function(_, text) {
      tr.append("<td>" + text + "</td>")
    });
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
  });
  tbody.appendTo("#trades_table");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="trades_table"  border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Updated to make `col3` as header

```js
var trades={
"test": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  },
"test2": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  }
};
$(function() {
  var tbody = $("<tbody />"),
    tr;
  $.each(trades, function(_, obj) {
    tr = $("<tr />");
    tr.append("<td colspan='5' align='center'>" + obj['col3'] + "</td>")
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
    tr = $("<tr />");
    $.each(obj, function(_, text) {
      tr.append("<td>" + text + "</td>")
    });
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
  });
  tbody.appendTo("#trades_table");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="trades_table"  border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: my god, how quick can a person be!

Thank you thank you so much!!!!! Been trying for ages.

Comment: will do, new account so takes some time. ty so much again!

Comment: is it also possible to have the values of one of the col's as the upper based table header?

so for example, make col3 the header

Comment: that does not work because obj[2] is in the loop after creating the seperate col with colspan

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through your JSON and create a new table for each occurrence.  You can find the number of columns with `Object.keys(YOUR_OBJ).length` :

```js
var obj = {
"test": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  },
"test2": {
  "col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3, "col4": 4, "col5": 5
  }
};

$.each(obj,function(k,v){
  var table = $(`
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="`+Object.keys(v).length+`">`+k+`</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `);
  
  $.each(v,function(k2,v2){
    $('tbody tr',table).append('<td>'+v2+'</td>');
  });
  
  table.appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
table{
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

td,th{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```